# empty output after recursive call issue

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is my code for 8 queen problem and why my output are all empty list (`[]`)?

I have checked this statement `print "result ok", result` will get non-empty results.

```
class Solution(object):

    def __init__(self, finalResult):
        self.finalResult = finalResult

    def Valid(self,result):
        currentX = len(result) - 1
        currentY = result[-1]
        if currentX == 0:
            return True
        for i in range(0, len(result) - 1):
            if result[i] == currentY:
                return False
            elif abs(i - currentX) == abs(result[i] - currentY):
                return False
        return True

    def NQueens(self, result):
        if result == []:
            row = 0
        else:
            row = len(result)
        for col in range(0, 8):
            result.append(col)
            if self.Valid(result) == True:
                # print "check valid ok", row, col, result
                if row == 7:
                    # print "result ok", result
                    self.finalResult.append(result)
                else:
                    self.NQueens(result)
            result.pop(-1)

        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    finalResult = []
    s = Solution(finalResult)
    s.NQueens([])

    print len(s.finalResult)

    for i in s.finalResult:
        print i
```

Output,

```
92
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Please edit the title from "weird empty output issue" to something more descriptive of the actual question or problem.

Comment: @m69, sure and done. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace

```
self.finalResult.append(result)
```

with

```
self.finalResult.append(result[:])
```

This will create a copy of the "result".  Your current code is creating several references to the same result which all get emptied by result.pop(-1)

Answer (score 2):

You have only one list `result` that you manipulate. When you append, you append a 'reference' to that list and then you keep modifiying it. At the end it is empty so you print 92 times that empty list. You just need to create a copy of the current `result` before appending it.

Comment: Thanks Julien, good advice. Any ideas to track all final results?

Comment: What do you mean by track? All your results will be in your `finalResult` list after you fix the small copy bug.